# 50 Degrees angle construction possible without protactor?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Is 50 degrees angle construction possible without a **protactor** or a **sine table** ?
Only using **Compass** and a **ruler**.

Comment: If making an angle of $50$ degrees was possible, then it would also be possible for $10$ degrees, because it is possible for $60$ degrees.

Comment: Well, since 10 degrees is the internal angle of a 36-gon, it can be made with trisector or neusis.

Comment: I need to explain my construction on the question is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes: edit your question and add a description of the construction.

Comment: i need 10 reputation for image

Comment: Can you link to an image?

Comment: @OscarLanzi  I need more reputation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to construct a $50$ degree angle only with compass and straightedge.

Constructing 50 degrees is aeqivalent to constructing $10$ degrees (since $60$ degrees is constructable). A $10$ degreesangle has order $36 = 2^2 \cdot 3^3$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass-and-straightedge_construction#Constructible_angles) states:

> The only angles of finite order that may be constructed starting with two points are those whose order is either a power of two, or a product of a power of two and a set of distinct Fermat primes.

Comment: Actually i have made it using a compass and ruler, and i wanted to upload an image but they dont allow unless you have a reputation of 10.

Comment: It depends on what is meant by a "ruler".  If you are allowed to use _marks_ on the ruler for measurements then the problem is easy (known  since Archimedes, really).  Taking no chances with language I always refer to a "marked ruler" vs. a "straightedge".

Comment: @OscarLanzi  I meant a straight edge here